# How do I run multiple requests in a batch?

Tags: java, solr, release, patch

Is it possible to run multiple solr requests in a batch? I would like to run multiple queries at once and get all the results in one request.

Comment: Sorry to say this i dont know to accet .. How to accept the answer

Answer (score 3):

[Query batching is a pending issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093). You can do the following (in descending order of usefulness):

- Implement the feature and submit it as a patch to the aforementioned JIRA issue.
- Collaborate with other people interested in this feature, by posting a suggestion to the aforementioned JIRA issue.
- Implement concurrent querying client-side (i.e. without any kind of support from Solr).
- Vote/watch the aforementioned JIRA issue.

Comment: Hoss Man made changes - 27/May/10 22:08 Fix Version/s Next [ 12315093 ] Fix Version/s 1.5 [ 12313566 ] .Hoss Man made changes - 06/May/11 20:44 Fix Version/s Next [ 12315093 ] Fix Version/s 3.2 [ 12316172 ]

Comment: What is that ... whether he fixed are not yet??

Comment: @Syed Abdul: no, it's not fixed. "Fix Version" indicates when it will potentially be fixed. Note "Status: Open" and "Resolution: unresolved". Also note there is no patch attached to the issue.

Comment: @Syed Abdul: posting "please add this feature" to JIRA does nothing towards solving the issue and annoys everyone subscribed to it (myself included). Please only post constructive and useful comments to JIRA.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you are still looking for this feature. If you are, you could checkout the patch I submitted recently.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093

We have been using it in our production servers and it has been running fine for more than a month now.

Answer (score 0):

not sure you can do that. You can only run one query at a time. If you want to run many queries at the same time, you can multithread your queries

Answer (score 0):

I did a fix on Karthick's solution.
If multi queries were sent, the resulting json would be invalid, since it'd have two or more "response" keys.
In this [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12809888/SOLR-1093-1.1.patch), each response has an identifier of the corresponding query.
Eg.:
{ "1.response" : ..., "2.response" : ... }

Notice: The patch should be applied with `patch -p1` and it was done from [lucene 5.3](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/releases/lucene-solr/5.3.0)